# setting sdk_container_image in flex template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In order to provide hermetic builds and runtime, we currently build custom flex template and worker images.  As part of deployment, we build the flex template and we can specify the custom flex template image but not the custom worker image - we have to pass it to dataflow separately when invoking the flex template. This creates hidden dependencies that we need to track as part of the release process elsewhere (and seems to go against the design of flex templates of being self-contained).  Is there a way to bake at least a default for the worker image ( sdk_container_image ) into the template?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to have a default for a template parameter, you can just use the the `@Default` annotation on it and change the default value for every template version you build. Though in this particular case, since `sdkContainerImage` parameter is declared in `DataflowPipelineOptions` in Java SDK (or `WorkerOptions` in Python SDK), and you can't control its default from the user code, I'd try to set the parameter value programmatically in the template code.

I think something like this should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
    DataflowPipelineOptions options =
        PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

    if (options.getSdkContainerImage() == null || options.getSdkContainerImage().isEmpty()) {
      // Set the default if not already set by the template runner.
      options.setSdkContainerImage("...");
    }

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    // ...
```

This is for Java, but you can do a similar thing with Python SDK.

Comment: Where can I find more about @Default - is that on the .json metadata template?

Comment: In Java SDK it's just the `org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default` annotation. [Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/1393583de32533b386ce092bc7b15ba9c9391493/v2/googlecloud-to-googlecloud/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/options/DataplexBigQueryToGcsOptions.java#L88).
In Python SDK, defaults are set slightly differently. [Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/3b5b00c9c9f1d70c3369394712f56b371feadb01/dataflow/flex-templates/streaming_beam/streaming_beam.py#L111).